# Different results in different downloading ways with ASIHttp

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, asihttprequest, nsoperationqueue

I was trying the ASINetworkQueue recently, in the process I encountered a very strange problem.

I tried to download a zip from server of around 30 MB size, when I was downloading using simple ASIHttpRequest the file downloaded in just 2 minutes, but when I tried to put that request in the ASINetworkQueue, the download time surprisingly increased upto 5 mins, it was so strange.. I am putting the code snippet if any one can say is there anything incorrect..

```
[self setNetworkQueue:[ASINetworkQueue queue]];
[[self networkQueue] setDelegate:self];
[[self networkQueue] setShouldCancelAllRequestsOnFailure:NO];
[[self networkQueue] setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
[[self networkQueue] setShowAccurateProgress:YES];

if (!progressBar)
{
    progressBar = [[UIProgressView alloc] init];
}
[[self networkQueue] setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressBar];
[[self networkQueue] setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
[[self networkQueue] setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
[[self networkQueue] setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueFinished:)];

NSArray *arrFilenames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Audio", nil];

for (NSString *strFilename in arrFilenames)
{

    NSString *strDestFolderName = @"Destination Path";


    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.zip", strDestFolderName]];

    if(!fileExists)
    {
        NSURL *url = <File Url to be downloaded>;

        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

        // This file has part of the download in it already
        [request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.zip.download", strDestFolderName]];
        [request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
        [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.zip", strDestFolderName]];

        [request setTimeOutSeconds:30];
        [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
        [request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];
        request.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: strFilename, @"fileName", nil];

        [[self networkQueue] addOperation:request];


    }

}




[[self networkQueue] go];
```

By using the above code it takes around 5 mins to download Audio.zip.. But when I do the following it takes 2 mins.

```
NSArray *arrFilenames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Audio", nil];

for (NSString *strFilename in arrFilenames)
{

    NSString *strDestFolderName = @"Destination Path";


    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.zip", strDestFolderName]];

    if(!fileExists)
    {
        NSURL *url = <File Url to be downloaded>;

        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

        // This file has part of the download in it already
        [request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.zip.download", strDestFolderName]];
        [request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
        [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.zip", strDestFolderName]];

        [request setTimeOutSeconds:30];
        [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
        [request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];
        request.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: strFilename, @"fileName", nil];

        [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
        [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
        [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressBar];

        [request start];


    }

}
```

Note - I was testing with only one file, not multiple, but my aim is to download multiple files..

Thanks.

Comment: Btw, ASI has been retired. It's recommended to use a more up-to-date framework like AFNetworking.

Comment: Yes I know, but the application is using it from a long time when it was alive. I have to live with it, until it asked to..